# How to calculate the average of a field using a date range

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I need to calculate the average of a number field called "Total" over a date range. I have a To and From date picker.

I'm sure this can be done in Sharepoint, but I have no idea of the logic to use.

Can anyone out there help me?

By the way, we are using Office365 Sharepoint.

Thanks,

Jeff Bolin

Comment: You want to create a calculated column using multiple list items data? If Yes, this is not possible. Calculated column can access the data of only single list item/row.

Comment: So, a total cannot be averaged over a date span?

Comment: Using Out of the box calculated column, it is not possible.

Comment: Are you trying to get the total from multiple list items? Correct me if I am misunderstanding anything.

Comment: Just one field title "Total".  But I need this total to be averaged over a date span for a final averaged total.

Comment: Are you using Modern experience or Classic experience?

Comment: It's set on classic right now, but can be changed.  This list is not in production as of yet.

Comment: Can you please add any screenshot of list view data? And explain how you want to calculate the Total? My understanding is you have 3 columns, Title, and two dates. You want to get the total from multiple list items/rows in list view.

Comment: I see what you are saying.  Yes, you are right.  Is there any other way in Sharepoint to do this?

Comment: Where is the "date picker"? A column? Custom form/html? A filter web part?

Comment: You need to create custom solution using code. Maybe using REST and fetch the data from list for the date range and then sum the total column.

Comment: Or if you just want to check the total one time then maybe you can create a list view by adding filters on date columns and Count on Total column from view settings.

Comment: The date picker is a "Date and Time" column.

Answer (score 0):

To average over a date column, modify view->in Totals section, choose Average for the date column:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Lisa.  Doesn't this average the entire list though?  I guess what I'm needing is some custom coding.  We've started using Sharepoint in Office 365 not long ago.  We were using Sharepoint 2010 on one of our local servers.  We had an Excel guru who actually made an Excel spreadsheet that pulled data from a Sharepoint list.  The data was for example, (Employees name, Total Score, To Date, From Date).  And once it pulls all of the scores for that employee, it will give an average of their personal scores.  Would be nice if MS expanded Sharepoint's calculated field abilities.